# python ping ip adress from txt file

Tags: python, operating-system, ping

trhe code take the ip adress from txt. when the server is online write in the new txt file. But this code write only the last file in the txt file.And never time goes in the else. I need help

tahnks

---

```
import os


file = open("IPs.txt","r+")

with open("IPs.txt","r") as file:

  for line in file:
     response =  os.system("ping   " + line)

     if response == 0:
        with open("IPsCheck.txt","w") as file:
            print(line)
            file.write(line)




     else:
        print("server not available ")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the output file (IPsCheck.txt) in append mode: "a+"

See here for more https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html#2

The code below seems to work. Change the DEBUG to False if you want to read the ips from the ips file.

```
import os

DEBUG = True

DEBUG_IPS = ['1.1.1.1', '8.8.8.8']

if DEBUG:
    ips = DEBUG_IPS
else:
    with open("IPs.txt", "r+") as ips_file:
        ips = [ip.strip() for ip in ips_file.readlines()]

with open("IPsCheck.txt", "w") as available_ips_file:
    for ip in ips:
        response = os.system('ping {}'.format(ip))
        if response == 0:
            available_ips_file.write(ip)
        else:
            print('server {} not available'.format(ip))
```

Comment: Thanks man. Thats works but it is going never in the else. This write all IPs in the txt

Comment: yeha. for example one of this ips is not available, but its going never in the else to print not available. Do you understand me what i mean ?

Comment: Yes - I understand. Try the code I have posted. It is a "cleaner" version of you code.Do you still face issues?